# Getting tkinter to display output in a textbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a small GUI that when the user enters a number into a text box, and it displays (as a label) whether it is a prime number or not.

The code I have currently "works" (as in no errors are displayed) but the label doesn't change.

The prime number code works in the python shell.

My code is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

label1 = Label( root, text="Enter Number")
E1 = Entry(root, bd =5)

def isPrime():
    entry1 = E1.get()
    entry1 = int(entry1)
    for d in range(2,entry1):
        if entry1 % d == 0:
            label1 = Label(root, text="Not prime")
            root.update_idletasks()
            break
    else:
        label1 = Label(root, text="Is prime")


submit = Button(root, text ="Submit", command = isPrime)
root.update_idletasks()

label1.pack()
E1.pack()
submit.pack(side =BOTTOM) 
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks for any help in advance, and please let me know if you'd like any more clarification about any issues. Thanks.

Comment: All those people using Tkinter still today...

Comment: You are replacing the label with a new one, instead of changing the existing Label. You should do `label1["text"] = "Is prime"` for example.

Comment: @AmitGold if you know the answer you should not be clicking the "Add Comment" button to post the answer.

Comment: @linusg what would you recommend instead of Tkinter for making GUIs with python?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I was reviewing so I didn't have the button.

Comment: Tk/Tcl is quite old and looks bad. I recommend wxPython for a good look and feel or PyQt/PySide. Think about porting your app!

Comment: I quite like Tkinter just for a simple way of practicing how GUIs work in Python :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-creating the `label1` everytime you click on button. Also, you are not packing the one you are creating since that one is in local scope of `isPrime()` method.

If you want to change the text of the label, you should pass it as parameter to `isPrime()` and use `.config(text="text here")` or `label["text"] = "text here"`.

```
def isPrime(lbl):
    entry1 = int(E1.get())
    for d in range(2,entry1):
        if entry1 % d == 0:
            lbl.config(text = "Not prime")
            break
    else:
        lbl["text"] = "Prime"

submit = Button(root, text ="Submit", command = lambda:isPrime(label1))
```

or you can make `label1` global and change its text.

```
def isPrime():
    global label1
    entry1 = E1.get()
    entry1 = int(entry1)
    for d in range(2,entry1):
        if entry1 % d == 0:
            label1.config(text = "Not prime")
            break
    else:
        label1["text"] = "Prime"

submit = Button(root, text ="Submit", command = isPrime)
```